# Javascript to ASP classic function for mobile device detection

Tags: javascript, mobile, vbscript, asp-classic

I was reading a lot of question about mobile detection, and a found a good one but it's JavaScript and I need it in Classic ASP.

```
function deviceType(userAgent) {
  userAgent=userAgent.toLowerCase()
  var mobile = (/iphone|ipad|ipod|android|blackberry|mini|windows\sce|palm/i.test(userAgent));
  if (mobile) {
    if ((userAgent.search("android") > -1) && (userAgent.search("mobile") > -1))
      return "Android Mobile"
    else if ((userAgent.search("android") > -1) && !(userAgent.search("mobile") > -1))
      return "Android Tablet"
    else if ((userAgent.search("blackberry") > -1))
      return "Blackberry Device"
    else if ((userAgent.search("iphone") > -1))
      return "iPhone Device"
    else if ((userAgent.search("ipod") > -1))
      return "iPod Device"
    else if ((userAgent.search("ipad") > -1))
      return "iPad Device"
    else
      return "Unknown mobile device"
  }
  else
    return"No mobile device detected";
}
```

I found a Classic ASP solution on http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ but the code just tell me if it's mobile or not while I need to detect and print the device type like the JavaScript function does.

```
<%
function deviceType(userAgent)
  dim b,v
  set b=new RegExp
  set v=new RegExp
  b.Pattern="(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino|android|ipad|playbook|silk"
  v.Pattern="1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-"
  b.IgnoreCase=true
  v.IgnoreCase=true
  b.Global=true
  v.Global=true
  if b.test(userAgent) or v.test(Left(userAgent,4)) then
    deviceType="Is a mobile device"
  else
    deviceType="Is not mobile"
  end if
end function
%>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite simple function and easy to port any language, I know but what about using the same function on server-side? Mixing JavaScript (it's Microsoft's JavaScript dialect called [JScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript) in fact) and VBScript is a built-in feature of Classic ASP.

```
<script language="JavaScript" runat="server">
function deviceType(userAgent) {
  userAgent=userAgent.toLowerCase()
  var mobile = (/iphone|ipad|ipod|android|blackberry|mini|windows\sce|palm/i.test(userAgent));
  if (mobile) {
    if ((userAgent.search("android") > -1) && (userAgent.search("mobile") > -1))
      return "Android Mobile"
    else if ((userAgent.search("android") > -1) && !(userAgent.search("mobile") > -1))
      return "Android Tablet"
    else if ((userAgent.search("blackberry") > -1))
      return "Blackberry Device"
    else if ((userAgent.search("iphone") > -1))
      return "iPhone Device"
    else if ((userAgent.search("ipod") > -1))
      return "iPod Device"
    else if ((userAgent.search("ipad") > -1))
      return "iPad Device"
    else
      return "Unknown mobile device"
  }
  else
    return "No mobile device detected";
}
</script>
<%
Dim strUA
    'convert request collection item into string, because JScript is picky than VBScript
    strUA = CStr(Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_USER_AGENT"))

Response.Write deviceType(strUA)
%>
```

Comment: really?!!!! I'll test it ASAP :* If it's works, you would save a poor front end from a lot of stuff. `<script language="JavaScript" runat="server">` never seen before :* :* :*

Comment: @Vixed yes I'm sure that javascript works on server-side in classic asp. the internet is full of examples like this.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean that you'd like the upper function converting, then it's fairly straightforward:

```
function DeviceType(userAgent)
    userAgent = LCase(userAgent)
    Dim mobile(), c, rV
    mobile = Split("iphone|ipad|ipod|android|blackberry|mini|windowssce|palm", "|")
    rV = "Unknown"
    For c = 0 To UBound(mobile, 1)
        If Instr(userAgent, mobile(c)) > 0 Then
            rV = mobile(c)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next 'c
    DeviceType = rV
End Function
```

It doesn't use Reg Exp, though. You can add more items into the bar separated list if you need to.

To summarise, the list (**iphone|ipad|ipod|android|blackberry|mini|windowssce|palm**) gets broken into an array based on the vertical bar (|) and each element tested (`If Instr(userAgent, mobile(c)) > 0`) and the result assigned to the return value (`... Then rV = mobile(c)`).

To be fair, I did forget the `(c)` from the `If Instr(userAgent, mobile) > 0` statement.

If you're looking for specific values in the user agent string, though, simply include them in the bar separated list. For instance, if you're looking for Android Tablet, then include `android tablet` (note the lower case) in the list:

> iphone device|ipad device|ipod device|android tablet|android mobile|blackberry|mini|windowssce|palm

Comment: but what about **Android Mobile** or **Android Tablet** ?

Comment: What about it? I've given you the body of the function, all you have to do is modify it to include other factors. You can do *some* of the leg work. This is a *simple* function.

Comment: I like your function, it's just that I don't understand how to place `else if ((userAgent.search("android") > -1) && !(userAgent.search("mobile") > -1))`

Comment: I've optimised the loop to exit when the occurrence is found, too.

Comment: I thought to do the same, but can't get it work because for table it's a part of  the user agent, so must be something like  **iphone|ipad|ipod|android|blackberry|tablet|mini|windowssce|palm**

Comment: All the routine is doing is searching for each of the array elements in the `userAgent` string. This string is passed as an argument to the function, so, irrespective of where, if any of the elements in the `mobile` array (i.e. iphone device, ipad device, ipod device, android tablet, android mobile, blackberry, mini, windowssce or palm) appear in the string then `Instr` will find it.

Comment: You should look up the meaning of the functions: [`Split`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/vbscript/vbscript_split_function.htm), [`Instr`](http://www.codefixer.com/tutorials/instr_vbscript_function.asp) and so on.